# What's causing this strange behavior?

Tags: c++

i was trying to solve this simple problem http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/158/B
and i came up with the code to solve it:

```
int main() {
int n,x,sum;
cin >> n;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cin >> x; sum += x;
}

for (int j = 1; j <= sum; j++) {
    double q = (sum*1.0) / j;
    if (q <= 4*1.0) {
        cout << j;
        break;
    }
}
return 0;
```

whatever the correctness of this solution, i noticed that nothing gets printed but if i changed this line

```
cout << j;
```

to this :

```
cout << ' ' << j;
```

it prints the answer (after the space of course).

i tested my code on ideone.com (here is the actual link to my solution http://ideone.com/wldwvy) and the behavior was as described above, but when i tested it on this site http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp0x_online.php the output was fine (with out having to include the space).

The completely awkward thing is when i tried to submit my solution to the problem on codeforces it gave me (time limit exceeded verdict) on a very small test case.

Why is this happening ?

Comment: My guess - Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't initialize `sum`, so `sum += x` is undefined behavior. Your code could do anything; the compiler is not required to detect the problem or do anything sensible about it.

Comment: In principle yes, but in practice the compiler will still allocate storage for `sum` with a garbage value, and the online compiler will not have any values of `int` that cannot be printed, so this will not cause empty output.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: And if that garbage value happens to be negative? Or if the compiler tries to optimize?

Comment: Ah, hadn't read the control flow of the program. A negative value causes the output line to be skipped. +1

Answer (score 0):

It may be an issue with `cout`'s buffer not getting flushed. It should also work if you do

```
cout << j << endl;
```

The reason adding a space worked is because it increases the content of the buffer, so that it is more likely to trigger an auto-flush.